# How can i add import statement during runtime in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am simply creating a program which takes the object name as input for ex. list, dict, tuple etc and stores all their associated functions in a text format.

**for instance:**

if 'list' is entered **Functions_Text_Files\list.txt** will be the location 
where my corresponding text file will be stored.

It is working fine for all but except for classes.

Say someone enters **collections** then either of the two ways must be satisfied (first anyone would not prefer):

- collections(or any such module must already be imported)
- if i add those modules by catching the exceptions (which i am unable to do)

**The Code is given below:**

```
import os
func_name = input("Enter the module of which you want the functions. :")
try :
    function_list = [i for i in dir(eval(func_name)) if not i.startswith("_")]
except NameError:
    eval("import "+func_name)
    function_list = [i for i in dir(eval(func_name)) if not i.startswith("_")]

file_path = 'Functions_Text_Files\\' + func_name + '.txt'
directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
    print("The Directory 'Functions_Text_Files' was not found.\nThis generally happens when you're running this first time."
      "\nCreating one!!")
with open(file_path , 'w') as file_object:
    file_object.write("Functions Associated with "+func_name.title()+" are :\n")
    for index, fname in enumerate(sorted(function_list)):
        file_object.write('{:>2}{} {}\n'.format(index+1,".",fname))
```

Comment: Look into [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) for importing modules rather than `eval`.

Comment: can you make the suggested edits.I am unable to get you;-(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the *inspect* module can help you to get things done. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). This could be a better approach than importing a whole module just to get the list of functions.

Comment: i don't think so it will work out . And if i will not import i won't be able to use   `dir(module)`.